# Implementing sort on the column headers of dataview webpart

Tags: data-view-web-part, custom-list

Is there a way that we can incorporate a sort on the column headers of the dataview webpart in share point 2010

Comment: Column headers should be generated automatically when you insert a DVWP onto the page.

Comment: i believe by default this functionality is available when u insert DVWP on a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to arranging columns based on their display name, there is no such OTB option.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to sort the columns alphabetically would be to simply change the column choices.  In the ribbon, select "Add/Remove Columns". Within that dialog, all of the columns are sorted in alphabetical order, so you can remove what exists, then add them all back to your DVWP **sorted**.